# I'm getting ERROR in Directive L10nDirective

Tags: angular, localization

```
ERROR in Directive L10nDirective in ...../angular-l10n.d.ts has no selector, please add it!
Cannot determine the module for class L10nDirective in ....
```

/node_modules/angular-l10n/angular-l10n.d.ts! Add L10nDirective to the NgModule to fix it.

```
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

ERROR in node_modules/angular-l10n/lib/services/l10n-routing.service.d.ts(10,17): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/angular-l10n/lib/services/l10n-routing.service.d.ts(11,17): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/angular-l10n/lib/directives/l10n-translate.directive.d.ts(8,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/angular-l10n/lib/directives/l10n-translate.directive.d.ts(9,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/angular-l10n/lib/directives/l10n-date.directive.d.ts(10,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/angular-l10n/lib/directives/l10n-number.directive.d.ts(10,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/angular-l10n/lib/directives/l10n-time-ago.directive.d.ts(11,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/angular-l10n/lib/directives/l10n-validate-number.directive.d.ts(17,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/angular-l10n/lib/directives/l10n-validate-date.directive.d.ts(17,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
```

I get this error when starting the angular application, I have added

my app.module.ts file

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { L10nIntlModule, L10nLoader, L10nTranslationModule } from 'angular-l10n';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { httpInterceptorProviders } from './http-interceptors';
import { LOCALIZATION_CONFIG, initL10n } from './localization-config';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        L10nTranslationModule.forRoot(LOCALIZATION_CONFIG),
        L10nIntlModule,
    ],
    providers: [{
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: initL10n,
        deps: [L10nLoader],
        multi: true,
    },
        httpInterceptorProviders],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "angular-latest",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --configuration=local",
    "start:int": "ng serve --configuration=int",
    "start:dev": "ng serve --configuration=dev",
    "start:prod": "ng serve --configuration=production",
    "start:localtoint": "ng serve --configuration=localtoint",
    "start:localtodev": "ng serve --configuration=localtodev",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "ng build --configuration=production",
    "build:int": "ng build --configuration=int",
    "build:dev": "ng build --configuration=dev",
    "build:localtoint": "ng build --configuration=localtoint",
    "build:localtodev": "ng build --configuration=localtodev",
    "test": "ng test",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "lint": "tslint -t codeFrame -p ./tsconfig.app.json"
  },
  "config": {
    "ghooks": {
      "pre-push": "npm run lint"
    }
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "angular-l10n": "^10.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "ngx-json-viewer": "^2.4.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "tslint-angular": "3.0.2",
    "tslint-config-ghx": "1.0.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.19",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.19",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

What is the error I'm doing here. any clarifications.

Answer (score -1):

Update angular version or degrade angular l10n version.
because angular l10n will work only with angular 10.
angular l10n 8.1.3 version will work with this angular version